# Why does DSolve make implicit assumptions when handing sqrt roots? Compare to Reduce

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

We all know that for real $x,y$ that $\sqrt{x y} = \sqrt{x} \sqrt{y}$ only when $x,y$ are nonnegative.   But Mathematica `DSolve` automatically does this when solving an ode. The question is why?

Here is an example

```
DSolve[y'[x] == Sqrt[x y[x]], y[x], x]
```

(*if you solve it by hand, how would you do this?*)

Mathematica gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How did it do it? It clearly rewrote `Sqrt[x y[x]]` as `Sqrt[x]* Sqrt[y[x]]` and made it separable and just integrated. This can be seen by calling WolframAlpha and looking at the step-by-step

---

```
 WolframAlpha["DSolve[y'[x]==Sqrt[x*y[x]],y[x],x]"]
```

[image]

---

Lets ask Reduce what it thinks about all of this

```
Reduce[Sqrt[x*y] == Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[y], Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Even if do not use `Reals` above

```
Reduce[Sqrt[x*y] == Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[y]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The point is, we can't just replace `Sqrt[x*y]` by `Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[y]]` without assumptions. Right?

This becomes more clear when adding assumptions to `DSolve` itself. Now it gives different answers depending if we tell it $x$ is positive or negative

```
DSolve[y'[x] == Sqrt[x y[x]], y[x], x, Assumptions -> Element[{x, y}, Reals]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DSolve[y'[x] == Sqrt[x y[x]], y[x], x, Assumptions -> {x > 0, y > 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DSolve[y'[x] == Sqrt[x y[x]], y[x], x, Assumptions -> {x < 0, y > 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This shows that the answer depends on the sign.

I am just trying to understand if Mathematica's answer is valid mathematically wise and why  it breaks the sqrt like this without using assumptions.

One possibility I was thinking about why the above can be done when solving the ode, is that the solution has an arbitrary constant of integration and that the constant of integration can be complex itself. But I am not sure that this will give one permission to break the sqrt as done here at the start. But that is what `DSolve` does.

When I solve this ode myself by hand, I will at least add assumptions that $x>0,y>$ before breaking up the sqrt. So may be if `DSolve` generated the answer with this assumption included, then that would be better.

V 13.2 on windows 10

Comment: This is not an MMA answer, so I am leaving it here as a comment: `(if you solve it by hand, how would you do this?)`. Well, the first observation is that $y(x)=0$ is a solution $\forall x$. So, let's find $y(x) \neq 0$. Divide LHS and RHS by $\sqrt{y}$ to bring it in the form: $(2 \sqrt{y})^{\prime}=\sqrt{x}$ which can be readily integrated to give $y = \left(\frac{1}{3} x^{3/2} + \text{constant} \right)^2$.

Comment: **Divide LHS and RHS by $\sqrt y$**
 @bmf thanks. But this is basically what Mathematica did. made it separable. But one can't do $\frac{\sqrt{x y}}{\sqrt y}$ and simplify it to $\sqrt x$ unless both are $x,y$ positive. And this is the main question I have.  Screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiErK.png) I think if I do this in the exam, the teacher might take off few points unless I explicitly say assuming $x,y>0$ before.

Comment: @Nasser Mathematica solves incorrectly the squared ode `y'[x]^2 == x y[x] `

Comment: @Nasser sorry for the delayed response, but I have a project that picked up and has lots of computations. We have established that we are looking for solution $y(x) \neq 0$. What I meant in my comment is that you can do [**`this`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLkB9.png). Without assumptions on $x$ and $y$, right?

Comment: @bmf but `PowerExpand` assumes all quantities are positive. From help, `The transformations made by PowerExpand are correct in general only if c is an integer or a and b are positive real numbers. ` so it is assuming $x,y$ are positive. We are back to square one. One can't simplify as `DSolve` did and break the sqrt without this assumption.

Comment: @Nasser oops, sorry. I forgot about that. (blushing). However, from the [**`docs`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) we see `PowerExpand makes special assumptions on input and is not used by FullSimplify`. So, we can get [**`this`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtMJL.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure W|A does not follow the steps of MMa in integration, so I'm unsure whether W|A and Mma solve ODEs in the same way. In any case, `DSolve[]` seems to produce a valid solution (with some restrictions on domain), some of which are valid for $x<0, y<0$ (e.g. $c_1 = -4i/3$ for the IC $y(-1)=-1$). I've never known `DSolve` to give restrictions on domain, but maybe it can. `Solve[]` can.

Comment: hello @MichaelE2  but if DSolve did not break up the sqrt as W|A did, do you know how else it would have arrived at the solution shown? By hand, that is the only way I see it happening myself.  I am not saying the solution it gave is wrong. But it is solution  which seems to assume (at least to me) that $x>0,y>0$. ie valid in this region only.

Comment: One could rationalize the equation and then the substitution $r=y/x^3$, $s = \log y$ turns it into an autonomous one. Then check the solution(s) on the original ODE. -- But I don't know whether Mma does something different or not.  BTW, the formula is valid for some $x<0,y<0$ even if the method was not. And you get an equivalent formula is one splits $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{-x}\sqrt{-y}$ for negative $x$, $y$. So the same result is valid in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eqn = y'[x] == Sqrt[x y[x]];

sol = DSolve[y'[x] == Sqrt[x y[x]], y, x][[1]]

(* {y -> Function[{x}, 1/36 (4 x^3 + 12 x^(3/2) C[1] + 9 C[1]^2)]} *)
```

Verifying the solution will provide the required constraints.

```
eqn2 = eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* Sqrt[x (2 x^(3/2) + 3 C[1])^2] == 2 x^2 + 3 Sqrt[x] C[1] *)

Reduce[eqn2, x, Reals] // ToRadicals

(* (C[1] < 0 && (x == 0 || x >= (-(3/2))^(2/3) C[1]^(2/3))) || 
  (C[1] >= 0 && x >= 0) *)
```